# How to preserve multiline TextBox/RichTextBox new lines in HTML mail body

Tags: vb.net, replace, outlook, richtextbox

I am trying to preserve new lines from RichTextBox (or normal TextBox if RTB will not work) while copying the `RichTextBox.Text` to HTML body in my Outlook mail.

I have tried many things over last couple of hours and nothing works.

I store RichTextBox text in variable like that:

```
Dim msg as string = RichTextBox.Text
```

Then I tried many things, like using Replace():

```
msg = msg.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>")
```

or other things (or other characters "\r\n") etc. and nothing works. The msg string when copied into Outlook HTMLbody is in one line without any change.

What am I missing in here? I have looked over SO for a few hours today and cannot find a solution.

Comment: The RichTextBox control uses `\n` as line separator. It replaces all occurrences of `\r\n` with just `\n` if the text you add contains any.

Comment: I have tried using \n separator in Replace() function but it does not work. The final result is still a single line string.

Comment: As `msg = msg.Replace(vbLf, "<br/>")`? What does the string look like after that?

Comment: Chaning <br> to <BR> helped. No idea why.

Comment: I suppose you were trying to replace `"\n"` with `"<br>"` in VB.Net. Won't do much.

Comment: You are right I suppose, thank you. Stupid mistake :) Are there any code lines regarding RichTextBox multiple spaces or tabs to replace them into html?